# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition takes too much to execute

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on a website that among other things has to calculate the distance between the user (mobile device or computer) and certain restaurants. The latitude and longitude values for each restaurant are stored in a database table. Here are the functions I'm using for calculating the device latitude and longitude:

```
        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                document.getElementById("geoloc_en_sts").value = true;
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError,
                    {
                        enableHighAccuracy : false,
                        timeout : 10000, // 10s
                    }
                );
            } else { 
                document.getElementById("geoloc_en_sts").value = false;
            }
        }
        function showPosition(position) {
            document.getElementById("user_lat").value=position.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById("user_long").value=position.coords.longitude;
        }
        function showError(error) {
            switch(error.code) {
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    //Do something
                    break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    //Do something
                    break;
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                    //Do something
                    break;
                case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                    //Do something else
                    break;
            }
        }
```

(I grabbed and personalized these functions from another stackoverflow answer)

The function showPosition stores the device's latitude and longitude values in a couple of hidden tags with id's user_lat and user_long. The idea is to have them in there for later use. Also, I must say I'm very new at web development and I don't know of better ways to pass parameters between javascript and PHP.

The function I'm using for calculating the distance between the two points is:

```
        function getDistance($id, $rest_lat, $rest_long) {
            var geoloc_en_sts = document.getElementById("geoloc_en_sts");
            if (geoloc_en_sts.value == "true") {
                var user_lat = document.getElementById("user_lat").value;
                var user_long = document.getElementById("user_long").value;
                var d2r = 0.017453292519; //   pi/180
                var long = (user_long - $rest_long) * d2r;
                var lat = (user_lat - $rest_lat) * d2r;
                var a = Math.pow(Math.sin(lat/2.0), 2) + Math.cos($rest_lat*d2r) * Math.cos(user_lat*d2r) * Math.pow(Math.sin(long/2.0), 2);
                var c = 2.0 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
                var e = (6378.1370 * c).toFixed(2);
                alert("Distance for restaurant ID " + $id + " is " + e " km";
            }
        }
```

(also, I grabbed this from another answer)

When querying my DB, I obtain the restaurants data in a JSON file and then for each record in it, I need to calculate the distance. Here is my code:

```
        $context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'=>'Connection: close\r\n')));
        $restaurants_json_url = "http://www.whateversite.com/restaurants/data.json";
        $restaurants_json = file_get_contents($restaurants_json_url,false,$context);
        ?>
        <script> getLocation(); </script>
        <?php
        $restaurants_array = json_decode($restaurants_json, true);
        $restaurants = $restaurants_array['restaurants'];
        $restaurants_result_count = count($restaurants);
        if ($restaurants_result_count > 0) {
            foreach ($restaurants as $restaurant) {
                $rest_id = $restaurant['id'];
                $rest_latitude = $restaurant['latitude'];
                $rest_longitude = $restaurant['longitude'];
                ?>
                <script> getDistance(<?php echo $rest_id.",".$rest_latitude.",".$rest_longitude ?>); </script>
                <?php
            }
        }
```

This function grabs the values previously stored in the hidden tags and makes the calculation. The sequence of events that I expect is the following:

1. The getLocation functions is called and executed
2. The showPosition function is called and executed. The device latitude and longitud values are stored in the hidden tags
3. The getDistance function is called as many times as record are in the database table. The distance is calculated each time.

My problem is that even though I call these functions in that order, the actual sequence of completion is not 1, 2, 3 but 1, 3, 2 instead. The showPosition function takes about 5 seconds to execute and by the time is is done, the getDistance function has already calculated wrong distances. I figured I either need to delay the execution of getDistance until showPosition is done executing or execute showPosition ahead of time so it is done by the time getDistance is called. The problem is that I query the DB using a $_POST and, for what I could see, every time the $_POST is executed, the hidden tag values are reset.

As I mentioned before, I'm very new at web development and there may be 100 different (better) ways of doing what I'm trying to do. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your codes are almost unreadable. it's need formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier way to do this would be through JavaScript and translating it by using Google Maps API. Most of the work is done for you so why not use it?

Also, just for a good practice:

Always use private, public, or protected infront of something. Also use classes

Comment: I'll study how to use the Google Maps API. Thanks for the tips !!